# Backup registry that stores file association data?

Tags: windows-registry, file-association

I want to backup only the registry that contain the file association data so after reinstalling windows i will be able to restore the file associations with restoring the registry. Which registry exactly i have to backup? I am using Windows 7 Ultimate x32.

Answer (score 1):

This information is located in [`HKCR`](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/termshm/g/hkey_classes_root.htm)(`Hkey_Classes_Root`).

> The *`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`* registry hive contains the information necessary so Windows knows what to do when you ask it to do something, like view the contents of a drive, or open a certain type of file, etc.

To be more practical for you, use a program to perform the backup.

For example [`RegFileExport`](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registry_file_offline_export.html) can do this for you.

> `RegFileExport` is a small console application that allows you to easily extract data from offline Registry file located on another disk drive. RegFileExport read the Registry file, ananlyze it, and then export the Registry data into a standard .reg file of Windows. You can export the entire Registry file, or only a specific Registry key.

Works on Windows 7.

Syntax:

```
RegFileExport [Registry File] [Destination .Reg File] {Registry Key}
```

- `{Registry Key}` Is optional, if the key is specified, only this key and all its subkeys will be exported into the .reg file. Otherwise, the entire file will be exported.
- if [Destination .Reg File] is an empty string `("")` the Registry data will be sent to the standard output.

Comment: Can i export the whole Hkey_Classes_Root hive using Regedit and then restore it after windows reinstall? Will this restore anything else except file associations that may cluster the registry on the new Windows install?